# Using Java Random Class

Tags: java

Please help. I am trying to use the Java `Random` class to draw spirals of random locations, size, color, etc. on drawing canvas. I am able to get the `Random` class to work when I call my `drawCurvedSpiral` method. However, sometimes it will print some of my spirals partially off the screen. So, how can I prevent this from happening? 
Below is what I have...

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Random;

public class AbstractArt
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    DrawingCanvas canvas = new DrawingCanvas();
    Graphics g = canvas.getGraphics();
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    int width = 25 + rand.nextInt(76);
    int arc = 0 + rand.nextInt(361);
    int x = rand.nextInt(canvas.getWidth()-width);
    int y = rand.nextInt(canvas.getHeight()-width);
    drawCurvedSpiral(g, x, y, width, width, arc, arc, getRandomCOlor());
    }
}
```

Comment: `x` and `y` start at `0`. This is the center of the arc. You need to translate those coordinates by `width/2`.

Comment: Modify `drawCurvedSpiral()` to avoid drawing any spiral that goes out of the bounds of the screen. Calculate the size of the spiral, then check if it goes of the screen relative to the passed values of `x` and `y`.